# How can I change the Size of the standard hamburger menu icon of a drawer in Flutter via theme

Tags: flutter, appbar

While creating the theme:

```
appBarTheme: new AppBarTheme(
          iconTheme: base.appBarTheme.iconTheme.copyWith(size: 100, color: Colors.red), 
          //Color is working but size having no effect*
        ),
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to change your hamburger menu is by changing your `leading` widget from the **AppBar**

```
final _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.menu, size: 40), // change this size and style
          onPressed: () => _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
        ),
        title: Text('Home Screen'),
      ),
      body: Container(),
      drawer: Container(
        width: 300,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
   );
}
```

This change will create this huge hamburger menu:

[image: Hamburger Menu]

Comment: So there is no way to change it once for all icons in the appbar via theme or something else?

Comment: Looks like nothing else works... I tried themes but the sizes parameters doesn't move from 24.0 Maybe you can create a provider who can set color and size for that leading Widget and do your trick.

Comment: I tried this solution and it works, however the huge drawback is that the hamburger menu will always be shown even if I want to have a back button after navigation to a new screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import 'dart:math';
    import 'package:app_with_bloc/util/MyScreenUtil.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class AppBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
      GlobalKey scaffoldKey;

    //  AppBar(this.scaffoldKey, {Key key}) : preferredSize = Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight), super(key: key);
      AppBar(this.scaffoldKey, {Key key})
          : preferredSize = Size.fromHeight(max(MyScreenUtil().getScaledSize(kToolbarHeight), kToolbarHeight)),
            super(key: key);

      @override
      final Size preferredSize; // default is 56.0

      @override
      _AppBarState createState() => _AppBarState();
    }

    class _AppBarState extends State {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MyScreenUtil().getScaledSize(4.0), left: MyScreenUtil().getScaledSize(4.0), ),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.menu, size: MyScreenUtil().getScaledSize(26), color: Colors.white), // change this size and style
                  onPressed: () => widget.scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(MyScreenUtil().getScaledSize(8.0)),
                child: Text('Start', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.apply(fontSizeFactor: 1.4, color: Colors.white)),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MyScreenUtil().getScaledSize(4.0), right: MyScreenUtil().getScaledSize(4.0), ),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.menu, size: MyScreenUtil().getScaledSize(26), color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ]
           ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```